# Does minecraft pocket edition require a user ID and log in?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My son used his birthday money to buy a kindle and downloaded minecraft pocket edition but my husband used my amazon account.  I'd like to de register it and redo it with his own account, but he's worried he will lose all his data from the app.  Does the pocket edition require the user to set up an account/ID?  Or will he lose everything?

Comment: I don't *think* so, but I'm not entirely certain on this, to be perfectly honest.

Answer (score 1):

No, Minecraft PE does not require the user to set up an account/ID.

(source: I have Minecraft PE and I did not have to set up an account (like I did when playing Minecraft on PC).  It was ready to play after installing it on the mobile device.

Comment: I am unsure if he will lose his game data when de-registering it and re-registering that game under his own account.  Be sure to do a full backup of the device and game data before making any changes just to be sure!

Answer (score -1):

No. When I played the Pocket Edition of Minecraft, I did not have to sign in with a log in or an ID.